# How do you position text box in excel ghantt chart?

Tags: excel, vba

How do you make the textbox and shapes move automatically and track the finish date when that date changes.
I have attached an image of the file

[text box location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyjuT.png)

Comment: Share what you have done and what issue you are facing. For shape position, there is `Top` and `Left` properties available in `Shape` object which you may use.

Comment: I want the shapes and textbox to automatically position themselves on the correct column if I change the date

Answer (score 0):

You may set the shape position using a specific cell position by following code:

```
Activesheet.Shapes("Shape Name").Top = Range("Cell Address").Top
Activesheet.Shapes("Shape Name").Left = Range("Cell Address").Left
```

To make it move automatically, use Sheet events like `Worksheet_Change()` and get the cell with updated finish date.